# Python regular expression to check start string is present or not

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression which should check start string of the  line and count some strings present in the line.

Example:
**File.txt**

```
# Compute
[ checking
a = b
a
a=b>c=d
```

Iterate this file and ignore the line with below condition

My Condition:

```
(line.startswith("[") or line.startswith("#") or line.count("=") > 1 or '=' not in line)
```

I need to re write the above condition in regex.

Trying the below,

```
re.search("^#",line)
re.search("^/[",line)
```

How to write this regex checking line starts with "#" or "[" and other conditions

Comment: `line.count("=") > 1 or '=' not in line` is equal to `line.count("=") != 1`, right?

Comment: Why not: `line.startswith(("[","#")) or line.count("=") != 1`?

Comment: It's obvious what the desired output is. It's specified in the question. A regex with  the same behaviour as the presented boolean condition.

Comment: @Ludisposed Ignore the lines which matches those condition.

Comment: Why rewrite it in regex as any regex solution will be slower than original

Comment: @MosesKoledoye {line.startswith(("[","#")) or line.count("=") != 1} . I have put that condition to make people understand the condition. I need to write a regex.thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you actually wish to use a singular regular expression, you can use the following pattern;

```
^[^#\[][^=]*?=[^=]*?$
```

Which will match everything that does not fit the logic you specified in your answer - and so will extract only things that don't fit the logic you provided, and so will ignore everything all lines with the conditions specified. This single pattern would save you mixing python logic with regular expressions, which may be more consistent.

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/aJu9sg/2)

Explanation:

- `^` anchors to the start of the string
- `[^#\[]` Makes sure there is not a `[` or a `#` at the start of the line
- `[^=]*?` lazily match any number of anything except an `=`
- `=` match exactly one `=`
- `[^=]*?` lazily match any number of anything except an `=`
- `$` end of string anchor.

---

You could use this, for example, with `grep` if you're running bash to extract all the matching lines, and so ignore all desired lines, or use a simple python script as follows;

import re
pattern = re.compile('^[^#[][^=]*?=[^=]*?$')

```
# For loop solution
with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if pattern.match(line):
            print(line)

# Alternative one-line generator expression;
with open('test.txt') as f:
    print('\n'.join((line for line in f if pattern.match(line))))
```

For your given output file, both will print out;

```
a = b
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first set of `startswith` conditions you can use `re.match`:

```
if re.match(r'[\[#]', text):
    ...
```

For the second condition, you can use re.findall (if you want the count):

```
if len(re.findall('=', text)) != 1:
    ...
```

You can combine the two above with an `and`, like this:

```
if re.match(r'[\[#]', text) and len(re.findall('=', text)) != 1:
    ...
```

Comment: @COLDSPEED Thanks for the answer